# Are there any historical accounts of Aisha (the wife of Muhammad) giving public speeches?

Tags: political-history, islam

The Wikipedia entry about [Aisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aisha) says:

> Aisha's importance to revitalizing the Arab tradition and leadership among the Arab women highlights her magnitude within Islam.[63] Aisha became involved in the politics of early Islam and the first three caliphate reigns: Abu Bakr, ‘Umar, and ‘Uthman. During a time in Islam when women were not expected, or wanted, to contribute outside the household, **Aisha delivered public speeches**, became directly involved in war and even battles, and helped both men and women to understand the practices of Muhammad.[32][additional citation needed]

The citation about Aisha delivering public speeches [32] refer to [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300055838) (page 51). I searched for "aisha speech" in the book but that didn't show any results.

[image]

According to John's comment, "the reference appears to be wrong."

**Are there any historical accounts of Aisha (the wife of Muhammad) giving public speeches?**

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: Don't understand the downvoting either. I am fearful that this stack may not have the expertise to answer it. I certainly don't.

Comment: @Brasidas You are misreading my question. I am asking for historical accounts not what the book says. I added the part about the book to show what research I have done.

Comment: The reference appears to be wrong. The book can be found online: go to books.google.com and search for "ahmed, leila women and gender in islam Aisha", without the quotes. However, page 51 does not mention Aisha making speeches, but is about the relationship between Aishia and Muhammad. Reading that chapter of the book, which is possible via books.google.com, might point you to more sources.

Answer (score 1):

Much of what I'm reading comes from [Short Biography of Aisha Int Bakr Al-Siddiq](http://www.usislam.org/pdf/Aisha-Youngest-Wife-of-the-Prophet-Muhammad.pdf)

[Battle of Camel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Camel), sometimes referred to as the battle of Jamal, November 7, 656, found A'isha (Mohommed's widow at this point) leading 3000 troops against Ali in the first Fitna (Moslem Civil war ), and talking peace terms with Ali before the battle and addressing the 3000 opposing Ali.

During his lifetime, Mohommed established her authority by telling Muslims to consult her in his absence;

> Mustadrak of Hakim, vol.4, p.11.
>   Men and women came from far and wide to benefit from her knowledge.

---

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith, by Abu Musa Al-Ash'ari Hadith 4.643. Musa Ibn Talha (r.a.) says,
>   "I did not see anyone more eloquent than Aisha"

After Mohommed's death, she went on to be become one of the most prolific and distinguished scholars of her time.

> A Muslim scholar, she is credited with narrating more than two thousand hadith. She had a great love of learning and became noted for her intelligence, learning and sharp sense of judgement.Aishah (r.a ) memorized quite a number of Surahs of the Qur’an. Her father was a man of learning and she inherited his love of knowledge.

There is a lot of writing about Aisha as a child bride.  I would just add that King John of England married 9-12 year old [Isabella of Angoulême](https://www.historyofroyalwomen.com/isabella-of-angouleme/isabella-angouleme-queen-england/) in 1200 so young brides happened in antiquity.

Comment: I am perplexed at the down votes; this seems to be supported. (The issue about child brides looks to be beyond the scope of the questions and would not harm this answer if deleted.  )

Comment: Aisha is a controversial figure for Moslems.  She fought against Ali which makes her extremely controversial for Shite.  She was an leader, scholar who is said in the Koran and Hadith to have both had the trust/respect of the prophet and was a leader of men.  Which makes her controversial for some other Moslems.